# If $k=dr$. how is $a^{k} = (a^{d})^{r}$?

Tags: group-theory

> Assuming $k,d,r$ are integers. If $k=dr$. How is $a^{k} = (a^{d})^{r}$?

What property of groups and cyclic groups is this?

Comment: It comes from associativity.  The two sides are grouping the same number of $a$’s in a different way.

Comment: I know this question specified that $k,d,r$ are integers, but to be safe I must stress that the identity need not hold true in the case of arbitrary exponents which aren't integers, in particular when negative or complex numbers are involved as the base.

Comment: @jmoravitz None of that is relevant in the context of group theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$k=dr$

$a^k=a^{dr}$

$a^k=(a^d)^r$

Going from the second to the third line is because of the general associativity property of the group operation. Applying the operation $dr$ times is the same as applying the operation $d$ times, then applying $a^d$ $r$ times:

$a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot a \: ... \cdot a = (a\cdot a\cdot ... \cdot a)\cdot (a\cdot a\cdot ... \cdot a) \cdot ... \cdot (a\cdot a\cdot ... \cdot a)$

Where the left side has $dr$ terms, and the right has $r$ parentheses terms, each parentheses with $d$ terms in it.

Comment: how are you going from first to second?

Comment: @KevinDudeja  *substitution*

Comment: substitution? Can we do that? What is this property? or is it general law of mathematics?

Comment: @KevinDudeja since $k$ and $dr$ are really representing the same number, the second line amounts to saying $a^k=a^k$.